# Angular flex has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'

Tags: angular, angular5

I am getting this error related to angular-flex

has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'

I am using

```
"@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a breaking change in RC1, so you need to freeze for now to beta12

```
"@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.12",
```

(Note the removed ^)